# Connection between parallelisable spheres and normed division algebras

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I was wondering if anybody knows an intuitive way to think about the equivalence that only ${ S }^{ 0 },{ S }^{ 1 },{ S }^{ 3 }$ and ${ S }^{ 7 }$ are parallelisable and the existence of only 4 normed division algebras     ($\mathbb{R,C,H,O}$). I know that one can use the normed division algebras to define n linear independent sections (on ${ S }^{ 0 },{ S }^{ 1 },{ S }^{ 3 },{ S }^{ 7 }$) but that doesn't tell me why there are exactly 4 of them. I first thought that the answer to the question boils down to lie groups, but ${ S }^{ 7 }$ is not a lie group.

I guess my question involves several sub questions:

1. Is there another way to think about a parallelisable manifold than that it has $n$ linear independent vectorfields or that the tangent bundle is isomorphic to the trivial bundle. (Both of them don't feel very intuitive to me.)
2. When you want to define a normed division algebra on ${ S }^{ 2 }$ e.g., which part of the definition does not work out? (Why can't one use the antipodal point as inverse elements.)
3. What is an intuitive/visual way to think about the equivalence above.

Comment: Your 2nd question is unclear. For the first question, the answer is negative. I do not think you will get a reasonable answer to 3, since this is a nontrivial theorem (in one direction).

Comment: Just leaving this here: 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763228/parallelization-of-a-sphere-gives-division-algebra

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't think that may second question make sense either because division algebras are not defined over manifolds. The question was more about the following. When you define a group multiplication on ${S}^{2}$ so that it becomes a lie group which part of the definition fails. But I guess there is no general answer, we only know that there isn't a group multiplication on ${S}^{2}$ not that for example every group multiplication is non-associative.

Comment: @ThorbenK But this post doesn't tell me why there are only 4 division algebras or what they have to do with parallelelisable spheres

Comment: @NicAG: In order to see which part of the definition fails, you have to specify the binary operation on $S^2$. For instance, one can define a binary operation which satisfies all the group laws but is discontinuous....

Comment: Another thing to know is that if you have a continuous binary operation $x*y$ on $S^2$ then  for every $g\in S^2$ there exists $x\in S^2$ satisfying $g*x=x$. In particular, the binary structure has to be non-cancellative, hence, not every element has an inverse (associativity is irrelevant here).